# Count only trailing elements of a number/string

Tags: python

Considering i have a number such as "`579700068780000000`". I would like to count only the trailing `0`'s in the number. So for the above number the answer would be `7` and not `10`. I have absolutely no clue as to how will I be able to do it.

I tried using the `.count` function but it returns all the 0's in the number.

Note: This is part of the codechef practice challenge [Codechef factorial problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do something silly like:

```
len(number) - len(number.rstrip('0'))
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x=='0',reversed(string))
```

However, this is likely to be less efficient than the `rstrip` case.

Comment: @mgilson - The 1st solution was brilliant!! I dont want to get into itertools yet as I am not very good with the basics